# Create a step chart in Flot using one data point

Tags: flot

How can I create a time-series flot step chart using one value with start-time and end-time. It should plot a straight line starting from start-time until end-time with the value of V.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mean something like in this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7mcjtats/)?

For that you need to create a dataseries with two datapoints like this:

```
var data = [
    [startTime, value],
    [endTime, value]
];
```